React Native Navigation WARN: The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator
Im having this warn in the console and I dont know how to solve it:
WARN  The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator. This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links for more details on how to specify a linking configuration.
Initially my code was this:
type RootStackParamList = {
  GameList: undefined;
  GameInfo: { gameId: string };
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="GameList">
          <Stack.Screen name="GameList" component={GameList} />
          <Stack.Screen name="GameInfo" component={GameInfo} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>

  );
}

Then I've correct my code by reading the doc and added this:
type RootStackParamList = {
  GameList: undefined;
  GameInfo: { gameId: string };
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function App() {
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://myapp.com', 'myapp://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        GameList: 'gamelist',
        GameInfo: 'gameinfo/:gameId',
        },
      },
    }


  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer linking={linking} independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="GameList">
          <Stack.Screen name="GameList" component={GameList} />
          <Stack.Screen name="GameInfo" component={GameInfo} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>

  );
}

But im still having the issue.
Maybe my linking config isn't well structured but idk how can I change
package.json:
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",

GameList.tsx
export default function GameList() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const itemsPerPage = 10;
  const navigation: any = useNavigation();
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetGamesQuery({ page });

  const paginatedGames = data?.results?.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage);

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    if (paginatedGames && paginatedGames.length === itemsPerPage && data?.results && data.results.length > page * itemsPerPage) {
      setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  };

  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    if (page > 1) {
      setPage((prev) => prev - 1);
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return <Text>Error loading games</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.paginationContainer}>
          <Pressable style={[styles.button, page === 1 && styles.disabledButton]} onPress={handlePreviousPage} disabled={page === 1}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Previous</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Text style={styles.pageText}>Page {page}</Text>
          <Pressable style={[styles.button, (!paginatedGames || paginatedGames.length < itemsPerPage) && styles.disabledButton]} onPress={handleNextPage} disabled={!paginatedGames || paginatedGames.length < itemsPerPage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
        {paginatedGames?.map((game: Game) => (
          <View key={game.id} style={styles.gameContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{game.name}</Text>
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GameInfo', { gameId: game.id })}>
              <Image source={{ uri: game.image.medium_url }} style={styles.image} />
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

GameInfo.tsx
type RootStackParamList = {
  GameInfo: { gameId: string };
};

type Props = {
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'GameInfo'>;
};


export default function GameInfo({ route }: Props) {
  const { gameId } = route.params;
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetGamesQuery({ page: 1 });

  const game = data?.results.find((game: Game) => game.id === gameId);


  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (error || !game) {
    return <Text>Game not found</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{game.name}</Text>
        <Image source={{ uri: game.image.medium_url }} style={styles.image} />

        <Text style={styles.title}>Description</Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>{game.deck}</Text>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Platforms</Text>
        <Text style={styles.platforms}>
          {game.platforms ? game.platforms.join(", ") : "Platforms not found"}
        </Text>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Release Date</Text>
        <Text style={styles.releaseDate}>{game.original_release_date}</Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}



Can you give us the link that’s being evaluated?

I dont have any deploy. Its a practice project
